# What to do with the olive oil from canned sardines?

Tags: oil, fish, canning, olive-oil, sardines

Olive oil is good for you, and it seems wasteful to throw it away.  Yet all recipes call for draining the sardines prior to usage.

Any good ideas on what to do with that olive oil?

Is it some bad kind of olive oil maybe?  Very low quality?  What would that even mean?  Some of the canned sardines say it's "extra virgin olive oil", which should be a good kind.

Comment: Asking what you can do with an ingredient is off topic, it may be better to edit this to ask if can you use the oil like regular olive oil.

Comment: You can use them as fuel for oil lamps or candles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, if you are going to use it, do so within a few days, and if you are not using right away, put in another container and store it in the refrigerator. As for uses, you can employ it anywhere you would use oil, and where the flavor works.  Certainly a vinaigrette or dressing.  I've seen suggestions for using it when roasting potatoes, and even on focaccia.  So, no need to dispose of it.  It is not going to be the best quality olive oil, and in some cases it is other types of oil.  However, if you enjoy the flavor and have a near term use in mind it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest dropping some oil on a slice of bread. Probably too simple to be called a recipe, it's just a sardine-flavoured version of bread with oil.

I'd would prefer to do this with the oil from canned anchovies, but with sardine or even tuna it's also fine.